# Animation with Margine in wpf

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

i am using this code for animate object from left side margin

```
ThicknessAnimation da = new ThicknessAnimation();
        double width = borderModel.Width;
        if (ConstantValue.HideShowModelPanel == false)
        {

            da.From = new Thickness(0,0,0,6);
            da.To = new Thickness(-width,0,0,6);
            da.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.8);
            ConstantValue.HideShowModelPanel = true;
        }
        else
        {
            da.From =new Thickness(-width,0,0,6);
            da.To = new Thickness(0,0,0,6);
            da.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.2);
            ConstantValue.HideShowModelPanel = false;
        }
        Storyboard.SetTarget(da, borderModel);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(da, new PropertyPath("Margin"));
        story.Children.Add(da);
        story.Begin();
        //borderModel.BeginAnimation(new PropertyPath("Margin"), da);
```

i wont to hide and show object. Please tell me where am i wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can have several reasons. Because you pasted not all of your code, i cannot analyse the following possibilities:

- Your storyboard is not correctly created
- Your borderModel is placed in a panel/contentcontrol, where the margin is ignored
- You have no "Width" specified for your borderModel

Assuming, you put your borderModel into a Grid i got your code working with small changes:

```cs
ThicknessAnimation da = new ThicknessAnimation();
double width = borderModel.ActualWidth;
if (ConstantValue.HideShowModelPanel == false)
{
 da.From = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 6);
 da.To = new Thickness(-width, 0, 0, 6);
 da.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.8);
 ConstantValue.HideShowModelPanel = true;
}
else
{
 da.From = new Thickness(-width, 0, 0, 6);
 da.To = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 6);
 da.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.2);
 ConstantValue.HideShowModelPanel = false;
}
   
borderModel.BeginAnimation(FrameworkElement.MarginProperty, da);
```